# How to show specific values in radio field?

Tags: odoo-11

Suppose I have a field in a view like below:

```xml
<field name="some_name" widget="radio"/>
```

where,

```py
some_name = fields.Selection([
    ('val1', 'val1'),
    ('val2', 'val2'), 
    ('val3', 'val3')
])
```

Now, suppose I have another view. There I want to get the field using xpath like:

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='some_name']"></xpath>
```

and there I want to display only the first two options of **some_name**. In odoo 11, How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in XML file:

```
<field name="some_name" attrs="{'invisible':[('some_name','==','val3')]}" invisible="1"/>
```